# Read data from USB 3.0 camera UWP

Tags: c#, .net, camera, uwp

I'm working with USB 3.0 Camera to display preview screen of it. But seems to Windows doesn't recognize it is Imaging Device so when I try to open Camera application default of Windows 10, it showed an error. 
So my question is how to take that USB 3.0 Camera like an Imaging Device that we can use it in UWP?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question correctly.

First you should enable camera/webcam capability in app's manifest.

Then try this:

```
MediaCapture _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
DeviceInformation deviceInfo = devices.FirstOrDefault();

if (deviceInfo == null)
    deviceInfo = devices.ElementAtOrDefault(0);

var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
    {
        VideoDeviceId = deviceInfo?.Id,
        PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Auto,
        StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
    };

if (deviceInfo == null)
    _mediaCapture = null;

if (_mediaCapture != null)
    {
        await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
        await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

If it doesn't works and `devices` does not contains camera you need, you shoud try to find yor device manually by device id/guid:

[image: Device manager screenshot]

```
// by (vendorid, deviceid)
string aqs = Windows.Devices.Usb.UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(0x1234, 0xabcd);
// or by device GUID
string aqs = Windows.Devices.Usb.UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(new Guid("camera guid"));
```

And when you get `aqs`:

```
var myDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
UsbDevice usbDevice = await Windows.Devices.Usb.UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);

// or try init MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
{
    VideoDeviceId = myDevices.FirstOrDefault()?.Id,
    PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Auto,
    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
};
```

Comment: The problem is UWP not recognize that USB 3.0 Camera is Video Capture device. So I cannot find it by DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync

Comment: It means what ```devices ``` does not contains your usb 3.0 camera?

Comment: Yes. It detected my camera is just a USB device, not the VideoCapture device.

Comment: Are you tried to get camera device by guid or deviceid? See my answer EDIT